# django haystack SearchField with indexed False

Tags: django, indexing, search-engine, django-haystack

Is there any reason to set additional fields with `indexed=False` into `SearchIndex`?

Documentation mentioned that additional fields should be defined for filtering or ordering results. By default `SearchIndex` has `indexed=True`, so what happens if I set `indexed=False`?

Will the data still be stored on index but not be indexed? What happens if I'd set `stored=False`?

How does it works?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

By default, all fields in Haystack are both indexed (searchable by the engine) and stored (retained by the engine and presented in the results). By using a stored field, you can store commonly used data in such a way that you don’t need to hit the database when processing the search result to get more information.  You get this advantage if you specify `indexed=True` and `stored=True`.

If you specify only `indexed=True`, you will be hitting the database when processing the search result to get additional information not available in the index.

The purpose of `indexed=False` is to cater for the scenario where you want a rendered field to follow a pre-rendered template during the indexing process.  A good example is illustrated here - https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#stored-indexed-fields