# django haystack field with indexed=False, does that improve search performance?, search is slow?

Tags: python, django, search, django-haystack, whoosh

I am a new bee. I read the whole django haystack tutorial, I am trying to make the search operation faster and looking the ways to optimize. I am using whoosh with haystack. SearchQuerySet().all (search engine is whoosh) operation is taking lot of time to load results. My SearchIndex class is

```
class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
      text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True) 
      product_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='product_name')
      product_name_ar = indexes.CharField(model_attr='product_name_ar')
      product_price=indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='product_price')
      product_price_old=indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='product_price_old')
      product_price_percentage=indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='percentage')
      product_price_amount_difference=indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='amount_difference')
      product_vendor_url=indexes.CharField(model_attr='product_vendor_url')
      product_image=indexes.CharField(model_attr='product_image')
      #foreign key references begin here
      product_vendor_name=indexes.CharField(model_attr='product_vendor__vendor_name', null=True)
      product_vendor_alias=indexes.CharField(model_attr='product_vendor__vendor_alias', null=True)
      product_vendor_logo=indexes.CharField(model_attr='product_vendor__vendor_logo', null=True)
      product_vendor_odeliver=indexes.CharField(model_attr='product_vendor__vendor_odeliver', null=True)
      product_vendor_website=indexes.CharField(model_attr='product_vendor__vendor_website', null=True)
      content_auto=indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='product_name')



    def get_model(self): 
        return ProductDeals

    def index_queryset(self, using=None): 
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated.""" 
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

the data template for the text field id

```
    {{ object.product_name }}
    {{ object.product_name_ar }}
```

i.e. only product_name and product_name_ar are going to be used for search operation. My question is regarding other fields, some of the fields(product_price, product_price_old, product_price_percentage, etc) are used to filter the results and other fields are used only to display information to the user. I have added the foreign key fields in the index to avoid hitting the database to make search faster. Accoriding the django haystack [documentation](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#stored-indexed-fields) by default all the Index fields are Indexed=True(the field is indexed) and Stored=True(field will be stored). I am assuming that my search operation is slow because of indexing and storing these many fields. In this context my questions are the following(which i could not understand from the documentation)

1. if this is my index class, what is the optimum way to set fields to make search faster.
2. does making Indexed=False for other fields makes any difference in speeding up the process(since these fields will be searched for to index)

my question is similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616766/django-haystack-searchfield-with-indexed-false), but the answer was not helpful for my case, and I cannot comment because of insufficient points.

additional code as requested
view:

```
class ProductsSearchView(SearchView):
"""My custom search view."""
#overriding parent properites
#SearchMixin Class properities
'''template_name = 'search/search.html'
load_all = True
form_class = ModelSearchForm
queryset = SearchQuerySet()
context_object_name = None
paginate_by = RESULTS_PER_PAGE
paginate_orphans = 0
paginator_class = Paginator
page_kwarg = 'page'
form_name = 'form'
search_field = 'q'
object_list = None'''
template_name='ksaprice_app/product_search.html'
context_object_name='context_var'
paginate_by=20
paginator_class = Paginator
#instantiating the form in the view
form_class=forms.ProductsSearchForm
# vendor_list=Vendor.objects.all().values_list('vendor_name')
# #to create list of unique vendors
# vendor_list_set = set(vendor_list)
# #converting set to list 
# vendor_list_unique=list(vendor_list_set)
# vendor_list_filtered=[]
vendor_unique_list=[]
sort_list=None
def __init__(self):
    super(ProductsSearchView, self).__init__()
    #extending initi here
    #self.sort_list={'relevance':'relevance','price_low_to_high':'price high to low', 'price_high_to_low':'price high to low', 'discount_high_to_low':'discount high to low', 'discount_low_to_high':'discount low to high'}
    self.sort_list=['relevance','discount % high to low','discount % low to high','discount amount high to low','discount amount low to high','price high to low' ,'price low to high']

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(ProductsSearchView, self).get_queryset()
    #by here the search query is getting executed
    self.vendor_filter=self.request.GET.get('select_vendor', 'all')
    self.search_query=self.request.GET.get('q', "")
    self.sort_by=self.request.GET.get('sort_by', "relevance")
    if self.vendor_filter!='all':
        filtered_queryset=queryset.filter(product_vendor_name=self.vendor_filter)
        #ordering when a particular vendor is selected
        if self.sort_by!='relevance':
            if self.sort_by=="discount % high to low":
                #for descending self.sort_by
                sort_with="-"+"product_price_percentage"
            elif self.sort_by=="discount % low to high":
                #for ascending self.sort_by
                sort_with="product_price_percentage"
            elif self.sort_by=="discount amount high to low":
                #descending
                sort_with="-"+"product_price_amount_difference"
            elif self.sort_by=="discount amount low to high":
                #ascending
                sort_with="product_price_amount_difference"
            elif self.sort_by=="price high to low":
                sort_with="-"+"product_price"
            elif self.sort_by=="price low to high":
                sort_with="product_price"
            elif self.sort_by=="popularity":
                #add logic later
                #sort_with="product_price"
                pass
            ordered_filtered_queryset=filtered_queryset.order_by(sort_with)
            return ordered_filtered_queryset
        return filtered_queryset
    elif self.vendor_filter=='all':
        #ordering when all the vendors are selected i.e. default
        if self.sort_by!='relevance':
            if self.sort_by=="discount % high to low":
                #for descending self.sort_by
                sort_with="-"+"product_price_percentage"
            elif self.sort_by=="discount % low to high":
                #for ascending self.sort_by
                sort_with="product_price_percentage"
            elif self.sort_by=="discount amount high to low":
                #descending
                sort_with="-"+"product_price_amount_difference"
            elif self.sort_by=="discount amount low to high":
                #ascending
                sort_with="product_price_amount_difference"
            elif self.sort_by=="price high to low":
                sort_with="-"+"product_price"
            elif self.sort_by=="price low to high":
                sort_with="product_price"
            elif self.sort_by=="popularity":
                #add logic later
                #sort_with="product_price"
                pass
            ordered_queryset=queryset.order_by(sort_with)
            return ordered_queryset
        elif self.sort_by=='relevance':
            #return query set without order and vendor
            return queryset
```

template:

```
  <div class="row">
{# {% for discount in context_var.products %} #}
{% for discount in context_var %}
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <!--<img src="{{static_url}}images/vendor/{{ discount.product_vendor__vendor_logo }}" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">-->
            <img src="{% static "images/vendor_top/" %}{{ discount.product_vendor_logo }}" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
            <img src="{% static "images/products/" %}{{ discount.product_vendor_alias }}/full/{{ discount.product_image }}" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            {{ discount.product_name }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <h5>{{ discount.product_price }}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <strike>
            <h5>{{ discount.product_price_old }}</h5>
            </strike>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <h5>{{ discount.product_vendor_odeliver }}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <h5>{{ discount.product_price_percentage }}</h5>
            <!--<h5>{{ discount.product_price_amount_difference }}</h5>-->

            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>




    <!-- if last column in row -->
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" and not forloop.last %}
    </div><div class="row">
```

Comment: When you say its slow, how much its slow? How many records you have indexed? and show how you are querying the results in view and rendering in template?

Comment: @AamirAdnan added the code of template and view..